# How to remove all instances of a specific character from a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database on MySQL where the data in the "Name" column contains unwanted carets (^). For example, a name might be "John^ Test^^". Is there any way to remove all these characters from the column?

Comment: you mean renaming all those columns ?

Comment: Yes, just go about: UPDATE myTableName SET name = REPLACE(myColumn, '^', ' '); and that will delete the unwanted char from all the rows un the name column ar once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help.

```
Update
  Yourtable
Set
  Name = replace(name, '^', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(myColumn, '^', ' ')
```